# React: Where to put an images for separate views

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've screens like **About, Portfolio, Contact etc**. Structure of sample views looks like `src/views/About/index.tsx`.

Where can I **put e.g human image for About view**? According to clear code standards.

Comment: Put it in the same folder as the component, then import it: `import Human from "./human.png";`. This will store an absolute URL in `Human` which you can now insert as `src` or the like. (not that this sounds opinion-based to me, and my comment is just that, an opinion)

Comment: Welcome, please provide more details (at least the relevant code snippet). Check out the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for more details on providing a solid question. Thanks!